# How to use jstack in mixed mode

Tags: java, linux, jstack

I try to use jstack in mixed mode to look at the native call stack, but I found jstack always display this error message to me.

```
sili@linux32:~$ jps
2834 Jps
2825 Server

sili@linux32:~$ jstack -m 2825
Attaching to process ID 2825, please wait...
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process
```

Without the -m parameter, everything is ok. And my os is ubuntu 11.04, output of java -version is

```
sili@linux32:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Also, my test program is very simple, as below. I try to use java that Oracle released, or gamma that myself built from source, to lanuch Server, but both of them can't work with jstack mixed mode.

```
import java.io.InputStream;  
import java.io.OutputStream;  
import java.net.ServerSocket;  
import java.net.Socket;  

class Server {  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(10000);  

        Socket accept = server.accept();  

    InputStream in = accept.getInputStream();  

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];  

    int num = in.read(buf);  

    String str = new String(buf,0,num);  

        System.out.println(str);  

        accept.close();  
        server.close();       
    }
}
```

According to Oracle's jstack page, mixed mode only can't work with remove debugger.

Comment: Did you mean remote debugger?

Comment: not remote debugger, just local

Comment: You need to enable process debugging at OS level. "$ echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope" this command can be used to enable it.